# Android cross-activity image cache

Tags: android

Suppose there're a couple of activities with the same drawables, for instance drawable-mdpi resources. I wonder if these resources get cached and reused on subsequent activities. Is it optimized a way so that the same drawable doesn't get loaded in the heap for each activity.

P.S. I'm writing an app that has 2-level-depth navigation and I'm using single activity to handle both levels with fragments. I just wonder if this approach has any benefits in terms of the heap load redundancy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you load a drawable onto an ImageView inside an Activity, the loaded drawable is going to be linked to the newly bound view in the Activity's view hierarchy. Because the View hierarchy for every Activity is closely tied with that respective Activity, that means its contents have a different place in memory. I don't see how you could change this.